# Build conditional fields in TO line of email

Tags: email, conditional

So I have checkboxes on an infopath form representing divisons in our agency.
Depending on who the form creator wants notified they check the boxes for Opertions or Admin, or Grant Management or some mix thereof.

When I am designing the workflow my flow was:

If Operations = yes then send email to sharepoint group for operations

If Admin = yes then send email to sharepoint group for admin

If Grant management - yes then send email to sharepoint group for grant management.

The problem is some people belong to more then one group and they get duplicate emails and no for other reasons I cant enforce them to only be in one group.

So if I send just a single email with multiple groups in the TO field it is smart enough to only send one email to a person belonging to multiple groups. So my question is is there a way to conditionally build the email groups checkboxed into the TO line of a single email in the designer workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do this, with the 'To' box - however if you change the 2nd and 3rd if statements to else if it may fix the problem that you are having with duplicate emails.

```
If Operations = Yes then Send an Email to {Operations}
else if Admin = Yes then Send an Email to {Admin}
else if Grant Management = Yes then Send an Email to {Grant Management}
```

If that doesn't work, you can add Stop workflow at the end of each if / else if statement, or a 'Go to stage' if you have more in your workflow (and are running a Sharepoint 2013 workflow)